# How to change the frequency of interstitial ads

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

Currently, my home page has 10 buttons and each button has an interstitial attached.

```
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, magic.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Loading an interstitial for each new `intent` is a little bit overboard though. How can I manipulate the interstitials to load after every 5 intents?

Comment: Are you getting any message while loading interstitial ad second time?

Comment: @VVB Nope. Loading the interstitials is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an integer

```
private int showbigad =0;
```

In OnCreate...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
int advalue = prefs.getInt("showad", 0); 
showbigad=advalue;
}
```

Now with each click we add to showbigad

```
EACHONEOFYOURBUTTONS.onClick....{
showbigad =showbigad+1;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("showad", showbigad);
editor.commit();
}});
```

Now if buttons have been clicked more than 4 times the interstitial ad will show

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()&& showbig>4) {
    mInterstitialAd.show();
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, magic.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: After adding `showbigad=0` under the `isloaded && showbigad>4` condition, it works perfectly. The oncreate part resetting the int to 0 doesn't work because the activity doesn't keep getting recreated, or if it does, then showbigad will never exceed 1.